# Converting frame.time to epoch

Tags: tshark

Using the following command what modifications need to be made to get frame.time as epoch in tshark?

```
tshark -T fields -n -r btle.pcap -E separator=, -e frame.time -e btle_rf.access_address_offenses -e btle_rf.channel -e btle_rf.flags -e btle_rf.flags.access_address_offenses_valid -e btle_rf.flags.channel_aliased -e btle_rf.flags.crc_checked -e btle_rf.flags.crc_valid -e btle_rf.flags.decrypted -e btle_rf.flags.dewhitened -e btle_rf.flags.mic_checked -e btle_rf.flags.mic_valid -e btle_rf.flags.noise_dbm_valid -e btle_rf.flags.reference_access_address_valid -e btle_rf.flags.rfu.1 -e btle_rf.flags.rfu.2 -e btle_rf.flags.signal_dbm_valid -e btle_rf.noise_dbm -e btle_rf.reference_access_address -e btle_rf.signal_dbm -e btle_rf.signed_byte_unused -e btle_rf.unsigned_byte_unused -e btle_rf.word_unused>btle.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are running Wireshark 1.4.0 or later, you can try changing `-e frame.time` to `-e frame.time_epoch`.  If you're running an older version of Wireshark, then I might suggest upgrading to a newer version.

With the latest stable version of Wireshark (2.2.7 as of this writing), all frame filters are documented in *View -> Internals -> Supported Protocols -> Frame -> ...* and you can always reference the online [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html) page as well.